Problem when running briefcase in dev mode - "ImportError: cannot import name 'Environment' from 'System' (unknown location)"
I am doing the BeeWare Python app tutorial, and I have made it to Tutorial 1 - Run the app in Developer mode, however I get an error and cannot figure out how to fix it.  It should run in dev mode and open up a GUI window, and mine says starting in dev mode... but never opens a GUI window, it gives me this error message instead: ImportError: cannot import name 'Environment' from 'System' (unknown location)
Problem running app helloworld.
How should I fix this, what is wrong?
I restarted and ran it again but got the same error. I don't even understand what is wrong?

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

You're more likely to get an answer on the Briefcase discussion page. Please include your Briefcase log file if one was created, or else Briefcase's complete console output.
